# Does $(k!)!$ equal $k!(k!-1)(k!-2)\cdots 1$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Does $(k!)!$ equal $k!(k!-1)(k!-2)\cdots 1$? Can this be shown simply?

Comment: That's true by definition.

Comment: It's almost the definition of factorial. Substitute $k!=n$, expand $(n)!$ and switch $n$ back to $k!$ in the resulting expression

Comment: @JacobClaassen He meant $3!!=3! \times (3!-1) \times ...\times 2 \times 1$

Comment: Yeah, I agree with $k!$ being equal to $k(k-1)!=k(k-1)(k-2)!$, but I don't see how this rule is the same as $k!(k!-1)(k!-2)\cdots1$.

Comment: $n!$ equals $n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots1$, even if $n=k!$ is itself a factorial.

Comment: Oh, got it. Didn't think to use substitution like that there. Thanks.

Comment: But note: there is a notation $n!!$ which does not mean $(n!)!$  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $k!=n$:

$$(k!)!=n!=n\times(n-1)\times(n-2)...\times 2 \times1$$

Now switch $n=k!$ back into the resulting expression:

$$(k!)!=k!\times(k!-1)\times(k!-2)\times...\times2\times1$$

Comment: I could be more formal and treat the cases where $k=1$ or $k=2$ separately, but I think it would confuse more than help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For each integer  $N\geq 3$,

$$1.2.3.....(N-2). (N-1).N=N!$$

replacing $N $ by $k!$, we find

$$1.2.3.... (k!)=(k!)!$$

$$=1.2.3... (k!-2). (k!-1). (k!)=$$

Answer (score 0):

$whatever!=whatever (whatever-1 )*....*1$

"Whatever" is ... whatever.

Can "whatever" be $n! $?  .... sure... whatever....